# After working with spring state machine breaks spring auto entity scan mecanism

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-statemachine

After i added dependencies of spring state machine my entities seen as not managed type. After adding @EntityScan annotation and tell Spring where to find entities used in our application, spring recognized my entities again. I am using following dependencies of spring  state machine.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.statemachine</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-statemachine-starter</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.statemachine</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-statemachine-autoconfigure</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.statemachine</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-statemachine-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

I think **spring-statemachine-data-jpa** is where the problem comes from. At documentation to get rid of any configuration problem they are using **spring-statemachine-autoconfigure**
and **@SpringBootApplication** annotation is enough to start application. But i am using **spring-boot-starter-data-jpa** to working on my database model.

Am i missing something about spring state machine? After adding **@EntityScan** everything working without problem but i am wondering what happened and auto scan was broken.

Comment: I had the same problem. I believe the spring-statemachine-data-jpa component scan is taking precedence. I've added to apply component

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're right. I had the same problem after including spring-statemachine-data-jpa dependency to my project.

Not sure what is the root cause, it seems like repository component scan from the lib is taking precedence.

To solve the problem, I manually mapped the unmapped repositories, by adding these to my main class

```
@EntityScan(basePackages = "name.your.package")
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "name.your.package")
```

and setting this flag for bean overriding to true

```
spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true
```

Comment: Thanks @Daniel Vilas-Boas for your answer. Any luck in finding the root cause for this issue?